# Is it possible to limit circuit and protect to 5 V whilst having a 5 V USB power in? I need around 1A current

Tags: power, current, usb, protection

I have a USB-powered circuit and would like to limit the voltage to 5 V for overvoltage protection.

I also require around 1 A for potential current draw.

Is this possible? Most solutions I find have limits to the current. I could probably get away with around 4.5 V of output.

I use a USB power supply to get the 1 A, not a PC USB port.

Comment: How sensitive is your device to overvoltage, or in other words, what is your load?

Comment: `could probably get away with around 4.5 V of output` close to 5 V - 5%. (USB PS with nominal 5.2 V are not unheard of.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already figured out how to draw 1.2 A from a USB port, or you're using some other less-reliable means of providing 5 V. If so, read on.

They used to make ICs for high-current overvoltage protection. For example, the [NCP346 from onsemi.](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/ncp346-d.pdf) However, it was discontinued with no replacement.

Similar parts (e.g. the [NCP360](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp360-d.pdf)) limit you to 600 mA. However, you might still be able to use this IC. It turns its output from high to high-impedance when an overvoltage is detected -- in other words, if you use it to drive an external nMOS on the ground return path, or invert it to control an external pMOS on the power path, you can still make it work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftEO7x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: C1 is from the part's datasheet; you'll need to test to determine if you need it, as its presence will slow your switching time. R1 is a pull-down to turn off the nMOS; 10 kΩ should be fine but note that the NCP360 can still output up to 37 μA in shutdown so R1 should be chosen to ensure M1 turns fully off.

Finally, make sure you don't short your `POWER IN -` to chassis or device ground which would circumvent this entire system. If you can't avoid it (probably due to the USB cable shield) then you'll need to invert this system and switch a pMOS on the positive rail instead -- which will require at least a second FET and a longer switching time.

Answer (score 2):

A USB 2.0 host has a VBUS pin that is 5V but it is only required to supply 500mA, so that won't work for you.

A USB-C host has a VBUS pin that is 5V and can supply up to 3A, so this can work for you. It is possible for a USB-C host to output more than 5V and more than 3A but only if your device includes a complicated intelligent Power Delivery mechanism. But by default (just add 5.1K pulldown resistors on CC1 and CC2) it will give you 5V @3A, no need for over-voltage protection.